# Change HTML on click

Tags: javascript, html

my problem on this read more button is, that when I close it by click on the #test_001 or #test_002 the read more button stays on: "read less" how do I change this ?

```js
$("#readmore_01").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_001").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(170, 170);
    let name = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("Read less");
    if(name == "Read less"){
        $(this).html("Read more");
    }

 });

$("#readmore_02").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_002").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(550, 550);
    let name = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("Read less");
    if(name == "Read less"){
        $(this).html("Read more");
    }

 });

$("#test_001").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_001").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(170, 170);


 });

$("#test_002").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_002").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(550, 550);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_01">
    <div>Hi guys that's a test</div>
    <p id="test_001" style="display:none">Test</p>
    <div class="toggleBtn_01">
         <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_01">Read more</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_02">
    <div>Hi guys that's a test</div>
    <p id="test_002" style="display:none">Test</p>
    <div class="toggleBtn_02">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_02">Read more</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do and what isn't working. Your example seems to be working as expected, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I wrote in the description what isn't working.

Comment: It doesn't stay on `read less` for me. It toggles the text.

Comment: It stays on read less if you close it by click on the text which appears after you click read more

Comment: You can find some answer on so. Search for « [javascript] change button html »

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your test_00# function calls.

When you click on the Test text, it calls the test_00# functions which have no logic to update the Read more/less buttons.

Add the following line in your test_00# functions to update when clicking the "Test" text.

```
document.getElementById("readmore_01").innerHTML = "Read more"
```

```js
$("#readmore_01").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_001").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(170, 170);
    let name = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("Read less");
    if(name == "Read less"){
        $(this).html("Read more");
    }

 });

$("#readmore_02").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_002").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(550, 550);
    let name = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("Read less");
    if(name == "Read less"){
        $(this).html("Read more");
    }

 });

$("#test_001").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_001").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(170, 170);
    
    document.getElementById("readmore_01").innerHTML = "Read more"
 });

$("#test_002").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    $("#test_002").toggle("fast");
    window.scrollTo(550, 550);

    document.getElementById("readmore_02").innerHTML = "Read more"
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_01">
    <div>Hi guys that's a test</div>
    <p id="test_001" style="display:none">Test</p>
    <div class="toggleBtn_01">
         <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_01">Read more</i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_02">
    <div>Hi guys that's a test</div>
    <p id="test_002" style="display:none">Test</p>
    <div class="toggleBtn_02">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_02">Read more</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ^^

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `var x` and `var y` in this context? They seem to be unused variables. Also, why does the first click handler have `if(name == "Read less" || $(this).id == "test_001"){` but the second one doesn't have `$(this).id == ...`?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones You are right, no reason to have var x.

Answer (score 1):

These functions can be abstracted a bit so you only need to have a single function to toggle this behavior.

First, we can define `Read more` and `Read less` as constants for better reusability (i.e. less error-prone to typos, and if you need to update the text, you only need to update this const value instead of updating a string value in multiple functions).

```
const READ_MORE = 'Read more';
const READ_LESS = 'Read less';
```

Then we can add this click handler to the `p` and the `div.toggleBtn_0x` so clicking on any of them will run this function.

```
.content_01 p,
.content_01 div.toggleBtn_01,
.content_02 p,
.content_02 div.toggleBtn_02
```

Once we're in the function, we can get the `i` and `p` elements to toggle by going to the parent, and then finding the relevant nodes.

```
let button = $(this).parent().find('i');
let text = $(this).parent().find('p');
```

I left out the `scrollTo` functionality because it wasn't clear how it was working in this snippet (probably because the example text is very short), but it should be fairly straight-forward to implement again as described at [Scroll to an element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/scroll-to-an-element-with-jquery).

Full example:

```js
const READ_MORE = 'Read more';
const READ_LESS = 'Read less';

$('.content_01 p, .content_01 div.toggleBtn_01, .content_02 p, .content_02 div.toggleBtn_02').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let button = $(this).parent().find('i');
  let text = $(this).parent().find('p');

  text.toggle('fast');

  if (button.html() == READ_LESS) {
    button.html(READ_MORE);
  } else {
    button.html(READ_LESS);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_01">
  <div>Hi guys that's a test</div>
  <p id="test_001" style="display:none">Test</p>
  <div class="toggleBtn_01">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_01">Read more</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content_02">
  <div>Hi guys that's a test</div>
  <p id="test_002" style="display:none">Test</p>
  <div class="toggleBtn_02">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" id="readmore_02">Read more</i>
  </div>
</div>
```